# Adding Login/logout functionality in school management system

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to add login,logout functionality
in the `Person` model so that any other class inherits it such as `guardians` `students` `staffs` can also get those functionality. How to do that and is there any better way?

```
from django.db import models


# simplified



class Person(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    BirthDate = models.DateField('Date of birth')
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    CellPhone = models.CharField(max_length=14)


class Guardian(Person):
    pass


class Student(Person):
    guardians = models.ManyToManyField(Guardian, db_table='Student_Guardian_Bridge')
    Address = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Staff_Type(models.Model):
    type_of_staff = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_of_staff


class Staff(Person):
    staff_type = models.ForeignKey(Staff_Type, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Salary = models.IntegerField()
    guardians = models.ManyToManyField(Guardian, db_table='Staff_Guardian_Bridge')
    Address = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're new to Django, No problem, I'm also developing a school management system:

https://gitlab.com/charanjit-singh/schoolmanagement

It's in Django, I've implemented the functionality you're asking, go to the link, clone the repository and check the views and models, let me know if there's any question on gitlab.

Comment: you've decorators like `login_required`, `user_passes_test`, etc, to implement the functionalities like that.